# GROUP BY en query

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x

Tengo una tabla con las siguientes columnas: `nombre`, `monto`, `fecha`.

Quiero en una query que se muestre la información agrupada por nombre y mes de la siguiente forma:

```
nombre1, suma(monto), marzo
nombre1, suma(monto), abril
nombre2, suma(monto), marzo
nombre2, suma(monto), mayo
```

¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literal, con [*"filtros y anotaciones"*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).

El ejemplo de la documentación, se explica por si mismo:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Count, Avg
>>> Book.objects.filter(name__startswith="Django").annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))
```

El filtro del mes es un poco más complejo, pero lo puedes ver de esta manera:

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.models import Sum

def index(request):
    get_mes = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'fecha')
    modelos= Modelo.objects.filter(fecha__year=YEAR).extra({'mes': get_mes})
    modelos_mes= modelos.values('mes').annotate(Sum('monto').order_by('mes')
```

Lo que hace el ejemplo es agregar un campo `month` a la consulta SQL, por un lado usando la interfaz con la base de datos y luego usa este campo para hacer los campos.

Actualmente uso `connection.ops.date_trunc_sql` sin problemas en una base de MySQL, pero no estoy seguro si funciona en otros motores.

Comment: Gracias Toledano, me sirve harto. Pero me gustaría que en vez de entregar el mes en formato fecha completa (2016-03-01), me lo entregue como 03 solamente. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Pues ya revisé en mi aplicación y el campo `mes` es un objeto de tipo datetime.datetime así la fecha que ves es una representación y puedes cambiarla como mas te convenga. Consulta http://strftime.org/ para conocer que opciones tienes.